# Python - TypeError: unbound method beamDeflection() must be called with beam instance as first argument (got list instance instead)

Tags: python

In Python, I am trying to run a function in a class and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 58, in getTotalDeflection
    beam.beamDeflection(loadsList, x)
TypeError: unbound method beamDeflection() must be called with beam instance as first argument (got list instance instead)
```

Code: beamModel.py:

```
class beam(object):

    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
         self.E = E  
         self.I = I  
         self.L = L  
         self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)] #[(Force, distance along beam)]

    def beamDeflection(self, Load, x):
        """Calculates defeclection at point x due to single load"""
        Force, distance = Load
        L = self.L
        E = self.E
        I = self.I
        b = L - distance
        i = (Force*b)/(6*L*E*I)
        j = ((L/b)*(x-distance)**3 - x**3 + (L**2 - b**2)*x)
        k = (L**2 - x**2 - b**2)
        if x > distance:
            return i*j
        else:
            return i*k

    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
    """Calculate total deflection of beam due to multiple loads"""
        loadsList = self.Loads
        beam.beamDeflection(loadsList, x)
```

Now I need to run a list of tuples through the function beamDeflection (which is working) and sum the results to give me the value of the total deflection, which should be returned by the function getTotalDeflection.

*EDIT:*

I changed the getTotalDeflection function to:

```
def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
    """Calculate total deflection of beam due to multiple loads
    """
    loadsList = self.Loads
    self.beamDeflection(loadsList, x)
```

which is now giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 58, in getTotalDeflection
    self.beamDeflection(loadsList, x)        
  File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 39, in beamDeflection
     Force, distance = Load
ValueError: need more than one value to unpack
```

Comment: Could you make it clearer which of your methods/functions are methods of the beam class, and which are module level. Your indentation suggests that `beamDeflection` is not an instance method of beam while the parameter `self` suggests it is.

Comment: @schwobaseggl is totallly right, the code you show is missing important elements. It seems like the indentation is wrong and it is hard to know if getTotalDeflection belongs to the beam object or not.

Comment: In fact, a good starting point for your study of Python may be to take a look at the style guide https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I have edited the post, sorry forgot to proof read.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be because you are calling `beamDeflection()` not on an instance of `beam` but on the static `beam` class itself.

Assuming that is the problem, you could probably rewrite your `getTotalDeflection` method like so:

```
def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
"""Calculate total deflection of beam due to multiple loads"""
    loadsList = self.Loads
    self.beamDeflection(loadsList, x)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error:

    
    _Force, distance = Load
    ValueError: too many values to unpack_

Comment: @Student1001 please show all the (relevant) code so that it is possible to help you.
Thank you Chris for the corrections : )

Comment: @Student1001 you did, except that you don't show the code from the beamDeflection() method, which is where the error is raised...

Comment: @Student1001 ok, so the problem you have is that `getTotalDeflection()` calls `beamDeflection()` with the Load parameter having more than two values. This creates an error at `Force, distance = loadsList` because python doesn't know what to do with the other values.

I would advise you to rewrite getTotalDeflection() to call beamDeflection() several times according to the length of loadList.